# Changing the blue onClick indicator of a ListView

Tags: android, listview, onclick

In my app I have a list view. I dont get how to custom `the native onClick indicator`. When I press on a view every thing with alpha component is showing a blue onPress mark.

If the view don't have an alpha component, then nothing will be shown. 
So, How do you "play" with what happens, when you press on a `view in a ListView`?

For example, in the Play Store you have a blue cover on top of every view that you press on? How can I do that?

And another question please, how can I disable this `onClick` indicator if I want?

Thanks!

Comment: you can add selector in listview

Comment: Thanks! why did you not put this as an answer? and also, do you know how to disable the native blue indicator?

Comment: Try these in attributes in ListView: `android:focusable="false"` `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

Comment: You are talking about the blue color when it is pressed and/or when it is set as selected in the list?

Comment: I am talking about the color when it is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[List selector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3alistSelector)  this is what you are looking for

you can add any drawable resource as list selector

Comment: Thanks! but how can I make it on top of the view and not beneath it?

Comment: Its with android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"! Thanks again!